# Tensorflow : NaN loss during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, nan, loss

We are trying to exeute the code below.

[Code](https://github.com/khazit/Lip2Word)

However, we are stuck in the nanloss problem in the Training process.

```
tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

Please help us

We use

1. OS : Windows 10 64bit
2. CUDA : CUDA 9.0
3. cudnn : CUDNN 7.0.5
4. Program : Pycharm(python = 3.6)
5. Tensorflow : 1.10.0

Data

1. Shape : (64, 1856) - 29 vertical lip photos of 64*64 size
2. Type : int32 - convert to float32
3. Statistics : 54690 train data, 6569 validation data
4. Labels : 100 words

```
    # Create the estimator
    print("Creating the custom estimator")
    cnn_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        model_dir=model_dir,
        params=params
    )

    if debugging :
        print("DEBUGGING MODE ENABLED")
        print("Training classifier for {} steps".format(n_steps))
        cnn_classifier.train(
            input_fn=lambda:input_fn(
                is_training=True,
                num_epochs=-1,
                filenames=train_filenames[:10],
                labels=train_labels[:10],
                batch_size=1
            ),
            steps=n_steps
        )
    else :
        # If the number of epochs is not defined (= 0), then train on number of
        # steps and evaluate at the end of the training ...
        if (n_epochs == 0) :
            print("Training classifier for {} steps".format(n_steps))
            cnn_classifier.train(
                input_fn=lambda:input_fn(
                    is_training=True,
                    num_epochs=1,
                    filenames=train_filenames,
                    labels=train_labels,
                    batch_size=1
                ),
                steps=n_steps
            )
            val_results = cnn_classifier.evaluate(
                input_fn=lambda:input_fn(
                    is_training=False,
                    filenames=val_filenames,
                    labels=val_labels
                )
            )
        # else train on multiple epochs and evaluate every epoch
        else :
            for i in range(n_epochs) :
                cnn_classifier.train(
                    input_fn=lambda:input_fn(
                        is_training=True,
                        num_epochs=1,
                        filenames=train_filenames,
                        labels=train_labels,
                        batch_size=1
                    )
                )
                val_results = cnn_classifier.evaluate(
                    input_fn=lambda:input_fn(
                        is_training=False,
                        filenames=val_filenames,
                        labels=val_labels
                    )
                )
        print("Results : \n{}".format(val_results))
    print("Done training")
```

```
def _build_model(inputs, num_classes, is_training):
    """
    Build the graph for the inception_v4 architecture
    Architecture :
        inputs          : (64 x 64 x  29)
        stem            : (12 x 12 x 192)
        inception_A     : (12 x 12 x 192)
        reduction_A     : (10 x 10 x 512)
        inception_B     : (10 x 10 x 512)
        reduction_B     : ( 8 x  8 x 768)
        inception_C     : ( 8 x  8 x 768)
        average_pooling : (          768)
    Args :
        - inputs : Tensor of the inputs
        - num_classes : number of number of classes
        - is_training : whether it's training mode or inference mode
    Returns :
        - logits
    """
    # Stem
    stem_output = stem(inputs, is_training)
    # Inception-A (x4)
    incepA_output = inception_A(stem_output,   is_training, '1')
    incepA_output = inception_A(incepA_output, is_training, '2')
    incepA_output = inception_A(incepA_output, is_training, '3')
    incepA_output = inception_A(incepA_output, is_training, '4')
    # Reduction-A
    reducA_output = reduction_A(incepA_output, is_training)
    # Inception-B (x5)
    incepB_output = inception_B(reducA_output, is_training, '1')
    incepB_output = inception_B(incepB_output, is_training, '2')
    incepB_output = inception_B(incepB_output, is_training, '3')
    incepB_output = inception_B(incepB_output, is_training, '4')
    incepB_output = inception_B(incepB_output, is_training, '5')
    # Reduction-B
    reducB_output = reduction_B(incepB_output, is_training)
    # Inception-C (x3)
    incepC_output = inception_C(reducB_output, is_training, '1')
    incepC_output = inception_C(incepC_output, is_training, '2')
    incepC_output = inception_C(incepC_output, is_training, '3')
    # Average Pooling Layer
    avg_pooling = tf.layers.average_pooling2d(
        inputs=incepC_output,
        pool_size=8,
        strides=1,
        padding="valid",
        name="average_pooling"
    )
    # Dense Layer
    dense = tf.layers.flatten(
        inputs=avg_pooling,
    )
    # Dropout (keep 0.8)
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
        inputs=dense,
        rate=0.2,
        training=is_training,
        name="dropout"
    )
    # Logits
    logits = tf.layers.dense(
        inputs=dropout,
        units=num_classes,
        name="logits"
    )
    return logits
```

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Model diverged with loss = NaN.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 187, in <module>
    input_fn=lambda:input_fn(
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 370, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1161, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1195, in _train_model_default
    saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1494, in _train_with_estimator_spec
    _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1259, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1345, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\monitored_session.py", line 1426, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata))
  File "C:\Users\82107\Desktop\Lip2Word_hangul__\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\basic_session_run_hooks.py", line 761, in after_run
    raise NanLossDuringTrainingError
tensorflow.python.training.basic_session_run_hooks.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

We looked up many solutions on the Internet and applied them, but they kept failing.

For example, we changed learning rate. It didn't do us much good.
And we changed optimizer Adam to everything. But It wasn't helpful for us.
Our data-type is float now.
We want to classify 100 words. So we check our train/validation labels. It was completely 100 kinds.

We are new to "Stack Overflow". So the question may be a bit immature. If there is anything we are missing, we will correct it right away if you tell us.

Comment: Check the input to the model, does it contain negative values, inf, NaN?
Also, don't post your entire code - too much to look at. Post only an overview of your input data (shape, data types, statistics) the actual model and fit code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And I'm sorry I posted the whole code. I checked the input data. It's shape is (64,1856). It has 29 vertical lip photos of 64*64 size. And It's data type is int32. But we convert data type to float32 in input_fn. We have 54690 train data and 6569 validation data that utter 100 words. And we also checked the input data to see if there was a negative number or NaN, but there was no.

Comment: And I edited my post succinctly. Thank for your advice :)

Comment: Can you reproduce the results from the repo?
Have you tried reducing your dataset to only one or two examples to determine if the behaviour due to the model or the dataset?

Comment: Thank for your comment. We have already reduced it to 3 train data and 3 validation data, but there has been no change.

Comment: All the info on the OS and other versions are irrelevant - this is not an installation issue. The attempt to find weights for the NN to fit the data is failing for mathematical reasons. What I meant by statistics is statistics per column. Start with a naive architecture with a few layers as possible and with simpler inputs and outputs e.g. a single label, less columns/pixels/frames. Check examples of input per possible output and see if you can see a clear difference between them.